# Using asp.net to save users data to Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Here is the scenario. The users would get a web page where they enter their employee id, skill set, name and press 'submit'.

On button click, I want the data to be copied to an Excel file on a server. Then next time a new user adds his data, it must be entered in next row and so on.

Is this possible the way I think or there is a need for proper database?

This project is just on a team level of around 50 members. Also if there is a user entry already present, HE must be prompted with update option of skill set instead of re-entering his info for second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good idea to store data directly in Excel file.

1. Store data in a database (sql/mysql/xml ...) therefore easily you can manage data and use database servers features.
2. Export database to Excel file anytime need data as Excel file

Comment: yeah I too  thought about same as it would be more structured and secure